# Spring Mongo Query, remove objects in collection matching list

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

How can I remove the objects from a mongo collection, by passing a list of objects to remove: I am using spring and mongo repository, below is my code:

```
 public void removeDocuments(List<PayloadLogs> listLogs){

     String collectionName = mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Logs.class);
     Query removeQuery = Query.query(Criteria.where("typeHash").in(listLogs));

// this does not removes the documents.
    this.mongoTemplate.findAllAndRemove(removeQuery, PayloadLogs.class, collectionName);
}
```

Query log:

```
db.getCollection('payloadLogs').find({
"creativeHash": {
    "$in": [{
        "creativeHash": "21540209fa87504bbbb0dd173c41d742",
        "lastAccessedAt": null,
        ....
    }]
}
```

});

Comment: You actually don't want to pass in the whole object. You just need a "unique identifier" or at least something that identifies the documents to remove from the collection. Either a single value or a list of values that matches the whole thing. In this case you just extract the `"creativeHash"` values as a list of those values only. Provided that does identify the documents to remove and it would not match other documents of course.

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn, lets say I have a list of objects fetch on some complex criteria already written. How can I remove these ? Or I need to create a new list with "logHash" only ? duplicating the records.

Comment: If you need a "list" with more than a single field value as criteria then you would use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/) instead. Since `$in` is essentially "shorthand" for `$or` on a single property, then that is the logical course. You should spend some time reading [Query and Projection Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/) and understanding where each is actually applied. Once you understand how each is actually applied, it answers a lot of questions.

Comment: @NeilLunn: If you can post your comment as Answer I will Accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be helpful, add your ids to list and will remove by ids

```
  BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(10004);
  list.add(10005);
  query.put("_id", new BasicDBObject("$in", list));
  collection.remove(query);
```